# Как сделать установленный Python3.6 основным при работе в Windows CMD?

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-2017, path, python-3.6

Установлен python3.6 и Microsoft VS с python на борту.Из командной строки windows cmd установка библиотек наподобие numpy идёт только для VS.

Открытие файла с VS python без проблем находит библиотеки установленные, но не стандартный python 3.6, хотя в папке файлы библиотек соответствующие имеются.

P.S. В PATH вроде прописан python 3.6.

Comment: что у вас `py -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` показывает?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте прописать в PATH полный путь к нужному вам интерпретатору с указанием файла запуска, т.е. будет примерно так: path = X:\python3_6\python.exe 
Или сделайте как на картинке, только укажите нужный вам путь до интерпретатора питона [image: Вот так это делается]
[image: Вот так в итоге получится]

Comment: В PATH обычно стоят разделённые точкой с запятой пути, т.е. лист путей. Что с ними?

Comment: Их оставить, как есть.